# input text field validation check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In login page i want to create form validation.

i wrote below mentioned code. but it does not work. i want to hide sign up button and show button when all the fields is not empty.

```js
function signupbtnactive (){

  var inputsignup = document.getElementsByClassName('input').val();

   while(inputsignup != null && !inputsignup.isEmpty()) {

            $('#signupbtn').show();

    };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sign-up-htm">

  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginusername" class="label">Username</label>
      <input id="newloginusername" type="text" class="input">
  </div>
 
  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginusersname" class="label">Surname</label>
      <input id="newloginusersname" type="text" class="input">
  </div>
 
  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginuser" class="label">Loginname</label>
      <input id="newloginuser" type="text" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginpwd" class="label">Password</label>
      <input id="newloginpwd" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginpwdconfirm" class="label">Repeat Password</label>
      <input id="newloginpwdconfirm" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="loginemail" class="label">Email Address</label>
      <input id="loginemail" type="text" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="loginemailcopy" class="label">Repeat Email Address</label>
      <input id="loginemailcopy" type="text" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="dobsignup" class="label">Date of birth</label>
      <input id="dobsignup" type="text" class="input" onblur="Checkemailsignup()">
  </div>

  <div class="group"  id="signupdivbtn">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="signupbtn" value="Sign Up" style="display: none;">
  </div>
</div>
```

above mentioned dont work. please advice what is problem?

Comment: where do you call the `signupbtnactive()` ?

Comment: You need to bind `change` event to all `input`s to find out if all of them have value or not. or using some `jQuery` plugin, there is lot of them out there.

Comment: getElementsByClassName('input') ?? you do not have any element with class name 'input'. It should be getElementsByTagName('input'). And of course when/where are you calling the signupbtnactive() function?

Comment: @SalaryNotFound i call function in html jsp file. my js code placed in main js jsp file. via  script type i call main js file in html tag. then in script i call signupbtnactive() but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var inputsignup = document.getElementsByClassName('inputField') ;
```

This will return all elements with the specified class.So.You have to loop through the each element and check if the value is empty

```js
function signupbtnactive (){

  var inputsignup = document.getElementsByClassName('inputField') ;
  var flag = false;
  for(var i in inputsignup){

    if(inputsignup[i].value== '' ){
      flag = true;
    }else{
      //console.log(inputsignup[i].value);
    }
  }
  if(!flag) { 
    $('#signupbtn').show(); 
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sign-up-htm">

  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginusername" class="label">Username</label>
      <input id="newloginusername" type="text" class="inputField">
  </div>
 
  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginusersname" class="label">Surname</label>
      <input id="newloginusersname" type="text" class="inputField">
  </div>
 
  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginuser" class="label">Loginname</label>
      <input id="newloginuser" type="text" class="inputField">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginpwd" class="label">Password</label>
      <input id="newloginpwd" type="password" class="inputField" data-type="password">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="newloginpwdconfirm" class="label">Repeat Password</label>
      <input id="newloginpwdconfirm" type="password" class="inputField" data-type="password">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="loginemail" class="label">Email Address</label>
      <input id="loginemail" type="text" class="inputField">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="loginemailcopy" class="label">Repeat Email Address</label>
      <input id="loginemailcopy" type="text" class="inputField">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
      <label for="dobsignup" class="label">Date of birth</label>
      <input id="dobsignup" type="text" class="inputField" onblur="signupbtnactive()">
  </div>

  <div class="group"  id="signupdivbtn">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="signupbtn" value="Sign Up" style="display: none;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have wrote your code in my project. JS code in main js jsp  file and html tag in jsp file then  call signupbtnactive () function in html tag, but  when i fill fields no result.

Comment: @IslamIsmayilov The function to show and hide the submit button is written on the blur of last input field in your code.This code is working properly in the snippet.Also FYI this is  not the best solution for your requirement.This is just a fix of your issue in the code

Comment: but onblur id= "dobsignup"  button shows despite all fields is empty how ist possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    //Set up the event listener to check every input when one changes
    $(".group input").change(checkInputs) 

    //function that checks all the inputs for values
    function checkInputs() {
        let $signUpButton = $("#signupbtn") 
        let $inputs = $(".group input") 
        let numOfEmptyInputs = $inputs.filter((i, input) => !input.value).length 

        if(numOfEmptyInputs  === 0) { 
            $signUpButton.show()
        } else {                        
            $signUpButton.hide()
        }
    }
</script>
```